# Invalid Key Hash . Facebook Android SDK 7.8 for Unity

Tags: android, facebook, hash, facebook-unity-sdk

Need Help about Facebook SDK 7.8 for Unity 5 ?

I keep getting the same error log:

> Invalid key hash. The key hash ********= does not match any stored key hashes."

[image: Error Screen Shot]

Previously when I get this error I removed the app and add it again and it starts working again and offcourse I can't do it again and again.

One more thing, the key hash he mentioned in the error is not the same I added in the app and if I go to app setting the key hash is correct there.

Note: it gives this error when I build release apk,but in debug mode it works fine.